# Is there a way to restart devices listed in device manager without restarting a Windows 10 computer and without opening the device manager?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to restart the device automatically after windows recognizes errors with It?

Sometimes when I start the PC I see onboard sound chip Realtek what ever mic and headphone/speaker however the speaker doesn’t work. Earlier I restarted the whole PC but now it’s not necessary. I just go as described to the device manager and deactivate then activate the devices.

The same I do for bluetooth. it's just a bluetooth dongle usb backsite ob the pc. Nice thing when I discovered I can not only connect my smartphone but also my headset with It. I had troubles with wifi 2.4 ghz and bluetooth and solved it with changing the wifi channel on the tp link accesspoint router to 4 and the channel width to 20 mhz. now one problem remains. After some time the bluetooth dongle or some driver gets problematic then I go to device manager and activate the deactivate the bluetooth dongle, then immediately the headset even connects with bluetooth wow!

How can this procedure happen automatically? Windows recognizes problem with hardware and driver, then I don’t need to restart it manually with mouse but windows restarts it automatically?

Comment: Does Windows detect the error or do "you" detect it by noticing undesired results?

Comment: its like one of these videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eydje93cPE4 audio stops working and i have to go to device manager first windows does something disturbing then i understand "lets go to device manager again..."

Comment: Restart can be done through a script, but if the audio just "stops working" and Windows doesn't notice an error, I don't have an idea how to trigger the script (except manually)?

Comment: Please don't link to videos, please add the appropriate screen shot to your question.